# How to wait until jQuery effects have finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How can I wait until an animation is finished in jQuery?

```js
function foo() {
  $("#element").fadeOut();
}
```

I need the `.fadeOut()` to complete before `foo()` returns because the calling code expects the DOM to be free of `#element`.

Comment: `$("#element").fadeOut( function() { // do your stuff } );`

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery animation functions have a `complete` callback. Because they are asyncronous you can't *wait* for them, you have to use callbacks.

```
function foo() {
    $("#element").fadeOut(function() {
        // finished
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery defines fadeout as: `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`, so using a callback should just work fine.

> complete Type: Function() A function to call once the animation is
>   complete, called once per matched element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function for this

```
function foo() {
  $("#element").fadeOut('slow', function(){
     // called when the element finishes fading out
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent `foo` from returning before the animation finishes. You need to use the callback or promise/deferred pattern. Here's how a callback could work:

```
function bar() {
    foo(function() {
        // stuff to execute after foo()
    });
}

function foo(callback) {
    $("#element").fadeOut('speed', callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').fadeOut(1000, function() {
  // after 1 second do something

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add a little explanation.